# Simple times table with For loop and arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm new to js, but very keen to learn. I want to make 2 "for" loops. 1. to store values of the 6 times table to an array (timesTable) up to 12x6. 2. Output these stored values to console (e.g 0 x 6 = 0, 1 x 6 = 0,). Thanks a lot.

```
<script>
    var timesTable = new Array();
    var multiplier = 6;

    timesTable[0] = 0 * multiplier;
    timesTable[1] = 1 * multiplier;
    timesTable[2] = 2 * multiplier;
    timesTable[3] = 3 * multiplier;
    timesTable[4] = 4 * multiplier;
    timesTable[5] = 5 * multiplier;




    console.log("0 x " + multiplier + " = " + timesTable[0]);
    console.log("1 x " + multiplier + " = " + timesTable[1]);
    console.log("2 x " + multiplier + " = " + timesTable[2]);
    console.log("3 x " + multiplier + " = " + timesTable[3]);
    console.log("4 x " + multiplier + " = " + timesTable[4]);
    console.log("5 x " + multiplier + " = " + timesTable[5]);


</script>
```

Comment: Okay, that sounds like you know exactly what you need to do. What is keeping you?

Comment: [Go ahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for 2 loops, you can do this in one:

```
var upTo = 12;
for (var i=0; i<upTo; i++) {
    timesTable.push(i*6)
    console.log(i + " x " + multiplier + " = " + i*6);
}
```

But if you really need 2:

```
var upTo = 12;
for (var i=0; i<upTo; i++) {
    timesTable.push(i*6)
}

for (var i=0; i<upTo; i++) {
    console.log(i + " x " + multiplier + " = " + timesTable[i]);
}
```

Comment: thank you. but this code only outputs:                                                      0 x 6 = 0
1 x 6 = 6
2 x 6 = 12
3 x 6 = 18
4 x 6 = 24
5 x 6 = 30            I need to 12x6

Comment: Awesome! If it worked, feel free to accept my answer so future users know it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily in one for loop and without an array to store it in.

```
var multiplier = 6;

for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    console.log(i + ' x ' + multiplier + ' = ' + (i * multiplier));
}
```

This will print the 6 times table up to 12. https://jsfiddle.net/o3k6feua/